# Asynchronously Write to Kinesis Stream from Java AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am asynchronously writing to a Kinesis stream from my Java Lambda function using the `AmazonKinesisAsyncClinet.putRecordAsync()` method.

The `putRecordAsync()` requests in the beginning of the Lambda function are appearing just fine in the Kinesis stream. However, the last few `putRecordAsync()` requests are not appearing in the Kinesis stream. The Lambda runtime environment is being killed when the end of the code is reached and not allowing the asynchronous put tasks to finish.

Is it possible to asynchronously write to my Kinesis stream from a Java Lambda function and ensure that all writes will be completed before the execution is killed?

Answer (score 1):

You can call kinesis.getExecutorService.awaitTermination() to make sure all threads are finished before returning.